# AWS S3 Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I follow the instruction of this answerd and got the same error.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1614469992506",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_Name>/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I got the error:

> Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

I check the documentation and I can't found any solution.

Comment: `ListBucket` should be on the bucket , not on the objects within the bucket. so, we need to split this policy into two statements. and take out `/*` in resource name for ListBucket

Comment: Allowing anonymous puts to your buckets is not a good practice. Are you sure you want to allow anyone in the world to be able to upload anything to your bucket?

Comment: The error you made in your policy may have inadvertently saved you a lot of pain and expense. This policy should never be applied to an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ListBucket should be on the bucket resource itself, where as the other Object Actions should be on the objects within the bucket. so, we need `/*` for all the objects of the bucket.

**IAM Policy**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_Name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_Name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Bucket Policy:**

Same as IAM Policy, except it has Principal attached.

`"Principal":"*"` or `"Principal":{"AWS":"*"}` will give public access and

`"Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::AccountNumber-WithoutHyphens:root"}` will give access to entire Aws Account.
Some details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html#Principal_specifying)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_Name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_Name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: To add to this, you can use the policy generator which will do basic validations and spit out the right policy that can be used.

https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Comment: @Raj, The policy generator miss the principal, and this statement was created with this tool

Comment: This is invalid bucket policy. Need principle.

Comment: @Marcin This is not a bucket policy , only an IAM policy. I don't believe question is about Bucket Policy

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Policy generator only generates resource-based policies.

Comment: Still Principal is needed like @Marcin suggested.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_Name>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_Name>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But you almost certainly shouldn't.