# How do I solve the "Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement" error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I am trying grant access to a S3 bucket for a CloudFront distribution and get this 400 Bad Request error:

> Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

I am using the AWS CDK for Python with the code as below:

```py
bucket.add_to_resource_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(
        resources=[bucket.bucket_arn],
        actions=["s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject", "s3:GetBucketAcl", "s3:PutBucketAcl"],
        principals=[iam.CanonicalUserPrincipal(canonical_id)]
    )
)
```

I have seen [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66404647/aws-s3-action-does-not-apply-to-any-resources-in-statement) asked however, modifying the actions do not seem to help, nor does using the wildcard * in the Resource element.

What's the issue?

Comment: Or to reverse the question, when using AWS management console, and editing Access Control List (ACL) under Permissions tab, is there a way to check what AWS does "under the hood"? I can grant the needed permissions through there (Objects: List, Write and Bucket ACL: Read, Write), but when I try to do the same with code, I get the error as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `s3:GetObject` & `s3:PutObject` permissions are **object-level** permissions, not **bucket-level** permissions - as per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-actions-as-permissions), you can see both actions apply to the `object` resource type.

On the other hand, the `s3:GetBucketAcl` & `s3:PutBucketAcl` actions apply to the `bucket` resource type so you can't combine and apply all 4 permissions against the S3 bucket.

This is why you get the error:

> Action (`s3:GetObject` & `s3:PutObject`) does not apply to any resource(s) (bucket) in statement' error.

You need to apply the object-level permissions to the *objects* in the bucket & the bucket-level permissions to the bucket, like so using the [`.arnForObjects(...)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3/README.html#amazon-s3-construct-library) method:

```py
bucket.add_to_resource_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(
        resources=[bucket.bucket_arn],
        actions=["s3:GetBucketAcl", "s3:PutBucketAcl"],
        principals=[iam.CanonicalUserPrincipal(canonical_id)]
    )
)

bucket.add_to_resource_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(
    resources=[bucket.arnForObjects("*")],
    actions=["s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject"],
    principals=[iam.CanonicalUserPrincipal(canonical_id)]
))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I struggled solving this even after vigorous googling. This seems to solve the error. However, I am still not getting the result I am expecting. After deployment I can see the bucket policy as expected in in AWS management console under Bucket policy under permissions tab. Yet, this hasn't added the canonical id and the rights under Access control list (ACL) heading. I wonder if I still need to use another method to add it as grant here. I will need to research more about it.